# MySQL/PHP: Identify site users who share their login credentials

Tags: php, mysql, security, account, dynamic-ip

I am trying to construct a `MySQL` query (or `PHP` script) to identify users who are sharing their web-login credentials with other people. I want to avoid forcing users to explicitly register their devices (like banks do), because I want to minimize the inconvenience for genuine users. I realize that there is no way to completely eliminate false positives or false negatives, but I want to do the best that I can.

At the time of log-in, the server stores the `ip address` , the `user id`, and the `browser fingerprint` ([fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2)) into a database. (The fingerprint is a semi-unique browser value).

If every user only used a single `ip` this would be a cinch - I'd just `SELECT` all users that have logged into the website from multiple ips. This is, of course, not the case. In the real world users may log in from multiple connections (e.g. work, home, phone), and in the case of `dynamic ips` the address itself can change.

Most users won't have more than 5 different connections (there are exceptions, but not many). I accept that there is (probably) no way to identify whether a single person is logging in from 5 different connections, or whether 5 different people are logging in from one connection each.

So long as my query only captures users who have logged in from *more than 5* connections, the "multiple connections per user" issue is out of the equation.

Now I must confront the issue of users with `dynamic ips`.

It is my understanding that most `ISPs` that provide dynamic connections will change only the last group of digits (I'd love some confirmation or stats regarding this).

If my query considers a "connection" to be the first 3 groups of `ip` digits, then the issue is settled for users with `ISPs` that change only the last group of digits.

Here is a simple `MySQL` query that I wrote. It groups distinct `ips` (without the last group of digits) by username and shows those usernames that are associated with more than 5 of these:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ip SEPARATOR '/') AS ips,
    username,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS n_ips
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT user_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip_address,'.',3) AS ip
        FROM
            ip_logins
        WHERE
            login_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY )
    ) AS weekips
JOIN users AS u ON (
    u.id = weekips.user_id
)
GROUP BY
    username
HAVING
    COUNT(n_ips) > 5
ORDER BY
    n_ips DESC
```

The way I intend to deal with "fully" `dynamic ips` (wherein any digit can change) is by counting all log-ins that share the same `browser fingerprint` as a single "connection". My reasoning is that if a user has logged in from multiple ips with the same `browser fingerprint`, then all of those log-ins are likely from a single individual with a "fully" `dynamic ip`. This doesn't fully resolve the problem, because it fails to account for users who use multiple browsers (since the browser fingerprint will be different).

I could use a cookie instead of `browser fingerprint`, but those could be deleted or disabled.

I would love some input on my strategy and some tips on how to improve it. If there is already an open source implementation of something like this (in `PHP`) - I'd like to know; no use in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why not just set a flag on their record and check that flag? "You're already logged in on another computer." You could put a time limit on the flag so if the user honestly tries to login from another computer they would be allowed to after the flag's time expired.

Comment: Because users may be logged in from multiple devices, and that is alright with us. We have many users that like to be persistently logged in on multiple devices, and I do not want to inconvenience them. Additionally, we want to be able to manually review the list of users before taking action. We intend to explain to them that sharing accounts is against our TOS, and force them to change their password.

Answer (score 2):

Why not start simple, like: detecting when a user is accessing the site from two or more IPs simultaneously, with a threshold of <30s between requests. That should already catch a lot of bad guys.

```
id  account_id  ip_address  time      page
1   1           1.1.1.1     00:00:00  /weather/amsterdam/today   <-- multiple IPs
2   1           2.2.2.2     00:00:05  /weather/london/yesterday  <-- on the same 
3   1           3.3.3.3     00:00:06  /weather/brussels/today    <-- account
4   1           4.4.4.4     02:02:02  /weather/paris/tomorrow
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to Jay Blanchard's comment - same answer. Also 30 seconds wouldn't do it for us. We have about 4k users and they pay $20/month each. Its unlikely that both the "sharER" and the "sharEE" would log on within 30 seconds of each other. (Or did I misunderstand your answer?)

Comment: Ah, from the query I see that you are storing the time the user logged in. I think if you'd log all _pageloads_ by the logged-in user, it should show you real simultaneous users. It really depends on the type of content you're offering though. Are you seeing a ten-fold of unique IP addresses logging in? Is it a site that one would want to use from multiple devices at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the utility in logging all pageloads.. maybe I'm missing the point. To answer your questions, yes for some users I do see a ten-fold of unique IP addresses logging in. It is a weather website, so there isn't a real reason why people would want to use it from multiple devices at the _same time_, but its unlikely that people would use it at the same time even if a person is sharing their account.

Comment: What I mean is that it may be easier to start with logging all _activity_ by a logged-in user and searching the dataset (see example in edit above) for accounts with activity from multiple IPs within a given timeframe. If you only log the login timestamp, it's still possible that that different IP would be the same _person_. If as you say it is very unlikely that the same account would be used from multiple devices (and therefore IPs) within a short timeframe, then a hit within a short timeframe is definitely a shared account.

Comment: Ah I see. That's pretty clever. I'll think about doing that. If I end up using it I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Kool. It's an interesting problem to analyse. Such detection can be implemented in great detail, as you've experienced. :)